# how to programatically edit the cell value of a datagridview in virtual mode?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, virtual, editing

I have a DataGridView in virtual mode.
I only implemented the CellValueNeeded eventhandler as described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc.aspx.

Implementing the rest of the events only seems needed when you want to be able to edit the cells manually.

I would like to programatically edit a DataGridView cell value.

I tried this using the following code:

```
DataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
DataGridView1.BeginEdit(false);
DataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = "testing new value";
//just using a random parameter here, not sure it is needed when editing programmatically
DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.LeaveControl);
DataGridView1.Refresh();
```

but no success :(

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use virtual mode, you provide your own logic for linking the `DataGridView` to the underlying data source. So, to edit a cell value, you should change the value in the underlying data source, and call `Refresh` to refresh the displayed value (this will cause the `CellValueNeeded` event to be called for all displayed cells)

Comment: Thank you.

Do you by any chance also know if there is a way to know which rows are currently displayed in virtual mode. This would give me a chance to determine if a refresh is necessary.

Comment: You can use the FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex and FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex properties, and the DisplayedColumnCount and DisplayedRowCount methods.

Comment: super! this control has so many properties that sometimes its hard to find what you are looking for. Thx a lot!

Comment: I've the same problem, I have bounded datagridview that is bounded to SQL datatable but when the user try to edit and add new rows to the datagridview it works fine and accept the edit with no issue 
but the issue appears when I want to edit cell value programmatically 
so how to achieve that ? Also I've debugged the code and I watched that the cell value is changed but it doesn't displayed on the gridview?